# Kafka: weight-based load balanced consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm pretty new with Kafka and i'm currently overwhelmed by the much lower level API that it offers compared to RabbitMQ (the previous message broker I was using). The problem i'm trying to solve is the following:

I have 3 topics:

- Topic 1: Has a weight of 10%
- Topic 2: Has a weight of 40%
- Topic 3: Has a weight of 50%

This 3 topics get filled with messages that I have to process. The workers read the message, do some processing and proceed to send using a HTTP POST that has a bandwith limit shared for all the 3 topics.

What I need:

If Queues 2 & 3 are empty, 100% of the available bandwith after processing should go to Queue 1
 - If more than one Queue has messages on it, the available bandwith should be distributed using the assigned 'weights' between the active queues.

At the moment, everything is working except for the 'weight' distribution (right now, they are distributed in a round-robin fashion). Priorities are not an option, since when using priorities, higher priority messages will be always delivered before lower priority ones.

Is there any option like this in Kafka? In RabbitMQ I had solved it assigning different prefetch values for each queue

Comment: I think Kafka aficionados don't like the term 'queue' and rather talk about a log. In fact it confuses the meaning of your question: do you mean topic or do you mean partition when you say 'queue'?

Comment: I think the correct Kafka term would be 'topic'. After refactoring my RabbitMQ code, I kept using the previous term, but I will update the question to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Kafka by now, this is not possible exactly how you want it. Lets put a few facts down:

1. Topics can be partitioned.
2. One partition is only ever processed by a single consumer. No two consumers can process the same partition. (This ensures messages ordering for two messages with the same key.)

Conclusion: the only way to get more CPU power for a topic is to have more partitions and a respective number of consumers.

You could set up the number of partitions according to your weights:

- Topic 1: 2 partitions
- Topic 2: 8 partitions
- Topic 3: 10 partitions

How many consumers? Use 10 consumers, 0...9, and let them subscribe to topics as follows:

- topic 1: consumer 0 and 1
- topic 2: consumer 2 to 9
- topic 3: all consumers

Now each consumer has to deal with two topics and the consumer ratios reflect your requested 5:4:1 when all topics have data. And when the first two topics dry out, there are still all 10 consumers working on topic 3 as required.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this; I think this is what I need. But i'm still curious to why you chose to assign consumers in that way: wouldn't it be more logical to assign 1 worker to topic one, 4 to topic 2 and 5 to topic 3?

I know several workers are always going to increase the message rate, but since they are limited and the limit is pretty heavy, I'm pretty sure 1 worker will be more than enough to handle 100% of the rate. Is there any other reason to divide the workers like you suggested?